JavaScript not finding css-variables - darkmode toggle in WordPress (webflow conversion)
I have an issue with my WordPress website and some custom JavaScript I want to use. The code gets loaded into the site with this script tag on line 16 in the head-section:
<script tr-color-vars="text,background,button-background,button-text,background-50,nav-menu-link,toggle-bg,toggle-offset"
duration="0.5" ease="power1.out"
src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/timothydesign/scripts@v1.0.2/dark-mode-toggle.js">

'tr-color-vars' lists the variables I'd like to change between light and dark-mode. 'src=' calls the cdn-hosted code.
In my webflow website, where I converted the theme from, the toggle works fine.
On the WordPress site, the code from the script returns the error-message:

No variables found matching tr-color-vars attribute value

Yet the variables are there.
Why does the js-code not find the variables? Any hint would be much appreciated.
live webflow site (working example)
link of wordpress site (toggle issue)
I got this code and the how-to from timothy ricks on YouTube: Tutorial
JavaScript code:
/**
 * Dark Mode Toggle 1.0.2
 * Copyright 2023 Timothy Ricks
 * Released under the MIT License
 * Released on: November 28, 2023
 */

function colorModeToggle() {
  function attr(defaultVal, attrVal) {
    const defaultValType = typeof defaultVal;
    if (typeof attrVal !== "string" || attrVal.trim() === "") return defaultVal;
    if (attrVal === "true" && defaultValType === "boolean") return true;
    if (attrVal === "false" && defaultValType === "boolean") return false;
    if (isNaN(attrVal) && defaultValType === "string") return attrVal;
    if (!isNaN(attrVal) && defaultValType === "number") return +attrVal;
    return defaultVal;
  }

  const htmlElement = document.documentElement;
  const computed = getComputedStyle(htmlElement);
  let toggleEl;
  let togglePressed = "false";

  const scriptTag = document.querySelector("[tr-color-vars]");
  if (!scriptTag) {
    console.warn("Script tag with tr-color-vars attribute not found");
    return;
  }

  let colorModeDuration = attr(0.5, scriptTag.getAttribute("duration"));
  let colorModeEase = attr("power1.out", scriptTag.getAttribute("ease"));

  const cssVariables = scriptTag.getAttribute("tr-color-vars");
  if (!cssVariables.length) {
    console.warn("Value of tr-color-vars attribute not found");
    return;
  }

  let lightColors = {};
  let darkColors = {};
  cssVariables.split(",").forEach(function (item) {
    let lightValue = computed.getPropertyValue(`--color--${item}`);
    let darkValue = computed.getPropertyValue(`--dark--${item}`);
    if (lightValue.length) {
      if (!darkValue.length) darkValue = lightValue;
      lightColors[`--color--${item}`] = lightValue;
      darkColors[`--color--${item}`] = darkValue;
    }
  });

  if (!Object.keys(lightColors).length) {
    console.warn("No variables found matching tr-color-vars attribute value");
    return;
  }

  function setColors(colorObject, animate) {
    if (typeof gsap !== "undefined" && animate) {
      gsap.to(htmlElement, {
        ...colorObject,
        duration: colorModeDuration,
        ease: colorModeEase
      });
    } else {
      Object.keys(colorObject).forEach(function (key) {
        htmlElement.style.setProperty(key, colorObject[key]);
      });
    }
  }

  function goDark(dark, animate) {
    if (dark) {

CSS variables:
:root {
    --swatch--light: white;
    --swatch--transparent: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    --swatch--brand: #8a2d59;
    --swatch--color: #1f1e3e;
    --swatch--dark: #201c1c;

    --color--background: var(--swatch--light);
    --color--text: var(--swatch--dark);
    --color--button-background: var(--swatch--brand);
    --color--button-text: var(--swatch--light);
    --color--toggle-bg: var(--swatch--light);
    --color--nav-menu-link: var(--swatch--light);
    --color--toggle-offset: 0rem;
    --color--background-50: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);

    --dark--background: var(--swatch--dark);
    --dark--text: var(--swatch--light);
    --dark--button-background: var(--swatch--brand);
    --dark--button-text: var(--swatch--light);
    --dark--toggle-bg: var(--swatch--brand);
    --dark--nav-menu-link: var(--swatch--light);
    --dark--toggle-offset: 2rem;
    --dark--background-50: rgba(53, 50, 51, .5);
}


Codepen Link this is simple darkmode switch I created using css variables & Js, you should check it out.

Thanks! Does it definately work in wordpress?

Not sure but you should try because at the end word press using css & Js. If you try then please share that it  worked or not.

I used the javascript from Timothy Ricks. It gives a lot of flexibility with the variables and it detect the browser default setting and automaticaly loads that mode.

The root of the problem was, that during the conversion of the webflow site into a theme (curtesy of udesly) the import of the css got moved below the script tag with the javascript.
After manually changing the script to load later than the css-variables it works like a treat.
working example

You have found best outcome by yourself, Great Work !
